# How to get http headers on a service in Jolie Programming Language

Tags: http, header, jolie

I have a service written in Jolie, where I want to extract the http headers on request. In the same way the request.id can be printed out, I would like to print the headers. There is a try on the bold letter down in the code. Here the code:

```
    execution { concurrent }



  inputPort UserDB_Service {
    Location: "socket://localhost:8002/"
    Protocol: http { .format = "json"}
    Interfaces: Users, ShutdownInterface, ConnectionPool
  }


  outputPort DB_Connector {
  Location: "socket://localhost:1000/"
  Protocol: sodep
  Interfaces: ConnectionPool
  }



init
{
connectionConfigInfo@DB_Connector()(connectionInfo);
connect@Database(connectionInfo)()

}

main
{
//Example: http://localhost:8002/retrieve?id=1
[ retrieve(request)(response) {
    query@Database(
        "select * from users where user_id=:id" {
            .id = request.id
        }
    )(sqlResponse);

    println@Console( "You have requested the user_id: " + request.id)();
    **println@Console( "Request Headers: " + response.format)();**

    if (#sqlResponse.row == 1) {
        response -> sqlResponse.row[0]          
    }

} ] 



}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It did not put in bold, but in the next format: **println@Console( "Request Headers: " + request.format)();**
And it is request, not respond. Sorry for the confusing argument. It is the request headers I want.

Comment: This question is badly worded and does not make much sense, but I upvoted, because it seems the first question about jolie, which seems an interesting language.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand if you know which headers you want to have in the inbound request or if you just want to print the whole http message for debugging purposes. It is quick in both cases, I report both solutions :)

In the first case you can set the `headers` parameter of the http protocol for the inputPort to include in the request message also the content of a specific header, e.g.,

```
http {
    .headers.format = "format";
}
```

and then you can inspect the value in the usual way

```
println@Console( request.format )()
```

In the second case, you can use

```
http {
    .debug = true;
    .debug.showContent = true
}
```

to see the log of all http requests and responses and their bodies.

These and further info on protocols and in particular the [http](http://docs.jolie-lang.org/#!documentation/protocols/http.html) protocol is in the documentation of the Jolie site.

Comment: It actually worked!
The headers are: 
         mar. 10, 2016 1:16:55 PM jolie.Interpreter logInfo
         INFO: [UserDB_crud.ol] [HTTP debug] Receiving:
         HTTP Code: 0
         Resource: /retrieve?id=1
          --> Header properties
               **  iv-user: g47257**
                   accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8,da;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
                   host: localhost:8002
                   upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
                   connection: keep-alive
                   cache-control: max-age=0
                   accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch

Comment: I wonder if I could extract the request header "iv-user" (I injected using fiddler), because it will be used for authentication sake.

I have this configuration now:
    inputPort UserDB_Service {
 Location: "socket://localhost:8002/"
 Protocol: http { .format = "json";
                  .headers.format = "format";
                  .debug = true;
                     .debug.showContent = true
                    }
 Interfaces: Users, ShutdownInterface, ConnectionPool
    }

Comment: Yes, try this MWE

   ` include "console.iol"

    inputPort Me {
        Location: "socket://localhost:8000"
        Protocol: http { .headers.iv_user = "ivUser" }
        RequestResponse: myRequest
    }

    main
    {
        myRequest( request )(){
           println@Console( request.ivUser )()
         }
    }`

Remember that, as reported in the [documentation](http://docs.jolie-lang.org/#!documentation/protocols/http.html), Jolie http.headers parameters map `-` in header names with `_`, e.g., in you case to target header `iv-user` we use `iv_user`.

Answer (score 0):

I put the output here again. I wonder if it is possible to extract the "iv-user: g47257" header, which I have injected by using Fiddler. Thanks again for the help. 
The headers are like this (better format).

```
INFO: [UserDB_crud.ol] [HTTP debug] Receiving:
HTTP Code: 0
Resource: /retrieve?id=1
--> Header properties
    iv-user: g47257
    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8,da;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
    host: localhost:8002
    upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
    connection: keep-alive
    cache-control: max-age=0
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp
 ,*/*;q=0.8
        user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36    (KHTM
L, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36

You have requested the user_id: 1
mar. 10, 2016 2:30:44 PM jolie.Interpreter logInfo
INFO: [UserDB_crud.ol] [HTTP debug] Sending:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Jolie
X-Jolie-MessageID: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 72

 ?V*H,..?/JQ?R*I-.Q?Q*-N-??♦
 ↑?(?%?"dRs‼3s?\►?????T♂ %??WE
 mar. 10, 2016 2:30:44 PM jolie.Interpreter logInfo
 INFO: [UserDB_crud.ol] [HTTP debug] Receiving:
 HTTP Code: 0
 Resource: /favicon.ico
 --> Header properties
    iv-user: g47257
    referer: http://localhost:8002/retrieve?id=1
    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8,da;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
    host: localhost:8002
    connection: keep-alive
    cache-control: no-cache
    pragma: no-cache
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTM
L, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
    accept: */*

mar. 10, 2016 2:30:44 PM jolie.Interpreter logWarning
WARNING: [UserDB_crud.ol] Received a message for operation favicon.ico, not   specified in the input port at the receiving service. Sending IOException to the  caller.
mar. 10, 2016 2:30:44 PM jolie.Interpreter logInfo
INFO: [UserDB_crud.ol] [HTTP debug] Sending:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Jolie
X-Jolie-MessageID: 0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 102

?VJ-*?/R??V?M-.NLOU?R??w?HN-(???S?QJ?O☺?→←↓↑↑?(?$?$???%?d?(?↨?▬%?¶Z)?%?e&???☺  ??Z ?yd?Y
```

Answer (score 0):

I re-post my last comment here since other people faced the same difficulties found by Efrin but might miss the solution I posted as a comment.

You can inspect the headers of a HTTP request as shown in the code below

```
include "console.iol" 
inputPort Me { 
  Location: "socket://localhost:8000" 
  Protocol: http { .headers.iv_user = "ivUser" } 
  RequestResponse: myRequest 
}

main { 
  myRequest( request )(){ println@Console( request.ivUser )() } 
}
```

Remember that, as reported in the [documentation](http://docs.jolie-lang.org/#!documentation/protocols/http.html), Jolie `http.headers` parameters map `-` in header names with `_`, e.g., in your case, header `iv-user` becomes `iv_user` in the Jolie HTTP protocol parameters.

Besides the description and code found in the Jolie documentation, you can find further examples and a more thorough explanation on how the HTTP protocol works in Jolie in its presentation paper wrote by Montesi https://doi.org/10.1016/j.scico.2016.05.002.